# How to figure out there are missing activities, in Android manifest file, with Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I've seen a number of people have problems because they don't add the activity to the manifest file. I've suffered from this myself.

This seems like such a simple/common problem yet I have no clue how I'm supposed to figure that out from the Eclipse IDE.

Is the debugging output of Eclipse totally useless or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: That is Android big illness. It lacks good error descriptions ((

Comment: Imho the error is pretty clear, it actually gives a hint "Did you forget to add the activity to your manifest?". And it's displayed in the LogCat, which is a View thats integrated into eclipse. It's just not open by default, thats the only flaw i can see.

Comment: Android logcat specifies the reason in the exception detail message.

Answer (score 6):

You can actually find that out if you're viewing `logcat` in the `DDMS`-tab of Eclipse. If you haven't added it, it throws an `ActivityNotFoundException` or similar exception, and even asks if one remembered to add the actitivy to the manifest.

Comment: Thanks!  That helps, though I still think android sucks.  I can understand throwing exceptions in my code, but eclipse keeps throwing errors at me.  No other IDE I use requires me to debug it. -- Most recently, it's generating null pointer expressions when trying to view my layouts -- I usually have to remove the project and reimport it.